# How to load elements in a table fully, to retrieve all IndexPaths?

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image]

I have this function in which I access from other classes to retrieve the indexpath of the relevant cells so I can edit the data within the cell dynamically across the App.

The problem is, when I update cells modified previously, I would like to modify them again once a user closes and re opens the app, but I am unable to access the cells past the 10th row. And I am assuming it is due to the fact the TableView only loads whats viewable at the moment.

Is there a way to force load all cells? Is my theory behind the problem right? Or is there a different approach I should be going about to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing directly into the cell, you should write towards a centralized data source (or Model by the MVC pattern).

Comment: What's a good example of a centralized data source? Is that using NSUserDefaults to store data locally?

Comment: Something like that, and then load that information into an Array, which then your table view can access the Array to find out what should be displayed in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Cool, yeah I was hoping to avoid using NSUserDefaults, not sure why again. But I see it being a common theme in MVC, as I am starting to understand MVC itself a little more over time. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use NSUserDefaults, you could save the data as a separate data file. You look it up.